# QEMU and SPICE on Win 10 host

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization, qemu

I am trying to run a Linux kernel based VM image (1) using QEMU on Windows 10 host. I have installed QEMU from https://qemu.weilnetz.de/w64/qemu-w64-setup-20190815.exe and SPICE client from https://virt-manager.org/download/sources/virt-viewer/virt-viewer-x64-8.0.msi .

I noticed that

`qemu-system-x86_64 -vga help`

does not list *qxl* as one of the available options.

Also,

`qemu-system-x86_64 -chardev help`

does not list *spicevmc* either.

Therefore, I assume I am either missing some drivers and libraries, or they exist, but somehow qemu binary on Windows is not aware of them.

Can anyone enlighten me how to run the VM using SPICE and have the QXL driver available? I might be missing something obvious, since I haven't been using MS products for anything serious until I was recently forced to.

(1) The image is based on https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/guix/guix-system-vm-image-1.0.1.x86_64-linux.xz .

Comment: >Mali Remorker Any results ?

Comment: @ilw I gave up eventually. Though, it could be that the situation improved over time [i think I recently saw something somewhere about running qemu on windows]. Anyway, check out the last windows Qemu builds.

Answer (score 2):

Not all Windows build include SPICE by default. You should ask the packager. I would bet SPICE is just not compiled in.

Answer (score 0):

For windows, [qemu recommends downloading the binaries from MSYS2's repos](https://www.qemu.org/download/#windows).

After following the linked instructions, I checked these binaries recently (version 8.2.0) and they have both spice chardev and glx vga included.

To get everything to work, in this case with GNU Guix as the guest system, I used the following qemu command:

```shell
qemu-system-x86_64.exe \
    -accel whpx \
    -nic user,model=virtio-net-pci \
    -m 2048 \
    -device virtio-blk,drive=myhd \
    -drive if=none,file=qemu-storage.img,id=myhd \
    -spice port=5930,disable-ticketing=on \
    -device virtio-serial-pci,id=virtio-serial0,max_ports=16,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5 \
    -chardev spicevmc,name=vdagent,id=vdagent \
    -device virtserialport,nr=1,bus=virtio-serial0.0,chardev=vdagent,name=com.redhat.spice.0
```

Then, launching virt-viewer Remote viewer, I connect to `spice://localhost:5930` (since this is the port I setup with qemu).